# Clicking deep link url opens the app with red border

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am doing an application which have deeplinking functionality. The deep linking will open a web-view class. If i click back, the app shows some random red colour border, when the app is been killed.The border not appears when the app is minimised.Do anyone know how to remove the red border.Thanks in advance.

I have already tried some of the solutions like disable strict mode.Its not working.I have written my code below about how i connect activity with deeplinking.

```
<activity android:name=".screens.PromotionsWebviewActivity">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:host="promotiondetails"
            android:pathPattern=".*"
            android:scheme="com.roxyapp.ios" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Does the activity you open contain any red border or anywhere around the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of enabled "strict mode". The screen flashes when app is doing long operations on main thread. You can disable it from developer options on your device. Read mode about strict mode here: [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode)